# How to load property file in main method java?

Tags: java, jar, properties

I am creating java application which reads property file from resource package. I have to do this in static main method. This will be fatJar. I tried

1)

```
File testProperties = new File(ClassLoader
        .getSystemResource("src/main/resources/p.properties").getFile());
```

2)

```
InputStream in = Example.class.getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/p.properties");
```

But nothing works. Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

The 2) option is closer.

You do want to use getResourceAsStream, however, your path is wrong. You need to know what the root of your class path is, and start there. Likely it's going to be

"/p.properties"

depending on how you build your jar. This has the basic maven layout so i'm assuming you are using that.